# Custom route does not work in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, url-routing

I am trying to implement my custom route in ASP.net MVC 3 but I get this error:

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

**global.asax**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "mycontroller", // Route name
         "{controller}/{name}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "MyController", action = "Search" } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Search(string name)
    {
        return Content(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @TGH yes i did see update above

Comment: See my answer, just update the MyController to My or even better change its name to a more significant one. You just need to refer to your controller as _<MyControllerDescriptiveName>_ and the convention to name controllers: _<MyControllerDescriptiveName>Controller_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "mycontroller", // Route name
 "mycontroller/{name}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "My", action = "Search", } // Parameter defaults
);
```

MyController won't be found because you don't have a controller named MyControllerController.  By virtue of inheriting from `Controller` the convention will be looking for the URL token + "Controller".

Cheers.

Comment: Also, remember that routes are greedy. Doesn't look like you'll run into that here, but the first route that matches will be the one that is executed, not necessarily the most specific. So put your *most specific* routes first. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "mycontroller", // Route name
 "{controller}/{name}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "My", action = "Search", } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Please register it in Global.asax file